# Is it normal for a integrated intel video card to have such low fps?

Tags: xorg, video

Here's the output from `glxgears`:

`300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.959 FPS`

My video card:

`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)`

I'm not sure if it's normal here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you see this message when you ran `glxgears`?

```
Running synchronized to the vertical refresh.  The framerate should 
be approximately the same as the monitor refresh rate.
```

If so, then that would likely explain the framerate of 60, which is probably your monitor's refresh rate. If not, the standard warning applies: `glxgears` shouldn't be used as a means of performance testing your video card.

Comment: yes , i did see that !

Comment: Do you know if 60hz is your refresh rate?

Comment: Yes , it was 60.1 hz

Comment: Mine is 60hz and has the same `lspci` signature as yours. I can't say if this is standard or not.

Comment: I'll bite: how do you glxgears so it's NOT synchronized to the vertical refresh?

Comment: You can do this `vblank_mode=0 glxgears`.

Comment: I'm encountering the exact same behaviour with a reported ~60 FPS. But how do you interpret this output? What does it mean?